# Make a segue from map view when annotation is clicked

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I am having trouble creating a segue from my Map view to another View Controller.  I want the user to click an annotation and have another view controller pop up.  I am having trouble creating the segue between the annotation press and the next view controller.  I named my segue from the map view to the navigation view Controller 'annotationPress'.  Whenever I click the annotations on the map, I get a new view controller that is all black.  Any advice would be appreciated.

```
    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!)
    {
//        performSegueWithIdentifier("annotationPress", sender: view)
    }


    override func performSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String?, sender: AnyObject?) {
        println("segueing...")
        if identifier == "annotationPress"
        {

        }

    }
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "annotationPress"
        {
            println("hello")
            var vc = MapRouteViewController()

        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't override function `performSegueWithIdentifier` just `prepareForSegue`

Also the `prepareForSegue` method your implementation is wrong (if you are trying to pass some arguments into destination view controller). You need something like this

```
let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! MapRouteViewController
```

Comment: and i think you should not create a segue from the mapview to the detailviewcontroller (does that work at all?) but from the viewcontroller that contains the mapview to the detailviewcontroller!